# Splitting from a file and adding to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, split

I am trying to split lines from a file and then trying to add the split string to a python dictionary, however, I keep getting the following error:

`'list' object is not callable`

A line from the file looks like

`a,12,15,16,17,18,92`

Here is my code:

```
filename = "numbers.txt"
file = open(filename, "r") 
xY = {}
xX = {}
for line in file:
    p = line.split(',')
    ID = p(0)
    a  = p(1)
    b  = p(2)
    c  = p(3)
    d = p(4) 
    e = p(5)
    f  = p(6)

    xY[ID] = [a, b, c]
    yY[ID] = [d, e, f]
```

Comment: change those parentheses to square braces: `p(0)` to `p[0]`

Answer (score 1):

`line.split(',')` returns a list.

You access elements of the list using the `[]` bracket notation

`list[0]` returns the first element in the list
`list[1]` returns the second element in the list
etc...

What you were trying to do was `list(0)`, which is a syntax error.

Python will interpret `list(0)` as an attempt to call a functor with the argument `0`. There is no function call operator for a `list`, hence the error:

```
'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: You could add that lists are not callable and that's why the error is being raised.

Comment: @Slayther done, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was just a typo/beginner error -- sequences are indexed or sliced using square brackets. Parentheses in python indicate a function call.

I'm adding answer to correct indentation errors and also make it more pythonic with list slicing:

```
filename = "numbers.txt"
with open(filename, "r") as file:
    xY = {}
    xX = {}
    for line in file:
        p = line.split(',')
        ID = p[0]
        xY[ID], yY[ID] = p[1:4], p[-3:]
```